Bootstrap 4 and Angular Expand all dynamically added accordion
I am doing the Angular code with Bootstrap 4 accordion as below.
How to add expand all and collapse all button ?
<div id="accordion">
<div *ngFor=" let Party of PartyF; let i = index;>
       <div class="card">6
              <div class="card-header">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" 
                        data-toggle="collapse" [attr.data-target]="'#data' + i" 
                        aria-expanded="true" [attr.aria-controls]="'data' + i">
                  </button>
              </div>
              <div [attr.id]="'data' + i" class="collapse" 
                  [ngClass]="{ show: i == PartyF.length - 1}" 
                  data-parent="#accordion">
                 <div class="card-body">  
                 </div>
              </div>
       </div>
  </div>


create an isExpended var in your component
export class YourComponent {
  isExpanded = false;

  toggleAccordions() {
    this.isExpanded = !this.isExpanded;
  }
}

bind it with each of the items
<div id="accordion">
  <button type="button" (click)="toggleAccordions()">
    {{ isExpanded ? 'Collapse All' : 'Expand All' }}
  </button>

  <div *ngFor="let party of PartyF; let i = index;">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link"
                data-toggle="collapse" [attr.data-target]="'#data' + i"
                aria-expanded="true" [attr.aria-controls]="'data' + i">
         titel:  {{ party.title }} 
        </button>
      </div>
      <div [id]="'data' + i" class="collapse" [class.show]="isExpanded" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
          Add your body here {{ party.body}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


above code is working only for collapse all and expand all button, what if one is collapse and other is expanded ?

the bootstrap data- resposible for collpasing each of the items. he asked for a solution for collapsing all
